# How to fix a warped laminate countertop?

Tags: cabinets

My washing machine over flowed for the last time before I gave her up, and the water warped my countertop that has laminate on top of particle board! It looks like it's cupped, bowed out on each end. It's also a corner cabinet. How do I fix this? Or do I need to tear it out? Your help is very very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry to say that there is no way to fix this other than replacement. Particle board cannot be "trained" back to shape and it will not return to shape when it dries. It is pretty much ruined after water exposure.

Comment: That's what I thought but I didn't know for sure. Add to it that it's a mobile home, I guess I'll just tear it out...thanks!

Comment: @AmberQuibodeaux No, take it out with care so you have the template for making the new one.